# How to implement a Linux update server?

Tags: linux, upgrade, services

I have a limited internet connection and I want to update all Linux PCs that I have(almost 30) but it will need every PC to download updates individually.
I need some service in Linux to download updates once and other PCs be able to get updates from that PC. Actually I need something like WSUS in windows server in Linux.

Comment: You should have put the operating system in the question, even if it is Debian.

Comment: all the systems are Ubuntu